# How to decode Firestore document ID for class that is both Codable & ObservableObject

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a class that boils down to something like this:

```
class GalleryPost: Codable, ObservableObject {
    @DocumentID public var id: String
    @Published public var myAttribute: String

    public init(_ myAttribute: String) {
        self.myAttribute = myAttribute
    }

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case myAttribute
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container: KeyedEncodingContainer<GalleryPost.CodingKeys> = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(myAttribute, forKey: .myAttribute)
    }

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container: KeyedDecodingContainer<GalleryPost.CodingKeys> = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        myAttribute = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .myAttribute)
    }
}
```

If the class is just `Codable`, I don't need to manually implement CodingKeys, an encoder & a decoder, and can use the `FirebaseFirestoreSwift` pod's support that provides @DocumentID to do it all for me, but this is not the case here due to `ObservableObject`. As `myAttribute` is marked as `@Published`, I need to manually make my class conform to `Codable`, yet my current setup no longer handles document IDs for me, and I have tried adding a documentId/documentID/DocumentID case but that only adds a new field in my Firestore data.

However, I still wish to set `id` to my Firestore document ID via my decoder. How can I do this? I am currently using a less elegant method that sets the `id` property elsewhere:

```
var post: GalleryPost? = try? queryDocument.data(as: GalleryPost.self)
if var post = post {
    post.id = queryDocument.documentID
}
```

Comment: have you tried setting in the init public init(_ myAttribute: String,id:String) {
        self.myAttribute = myAttribute
        self.id = id                                   }

Comment: I do not need to initialise my objects with a document ID, as Firestore handles the generation for me automatically. But when decoding, there should already be a document ID present in whatever Firestore is sending back for my query, but I don't know how or if it's possible to make use of their library to decode this for me elegantly just like how @DocumentID normally would for automatic encoding/decoding.

Comment: @Cloud did you ever figure out an answer to this problem? I am dealing with the same thing. I've been putting `_id = try values.decode(DocumentID<String>.self, forKey: .id)` in the decoder, but the id field is in the encoder too, and that creates a new ID field as well.

Comment: It's been a long time, I can't recall. I may have just stuck with the less elegant method.